# Using DHCP to get two different IP addresses for two NICs on one Machine

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I am using Debian 7.0.

I have one machine with two NICs connected and I want to assign two static IP addresses to this machine.

Here is my configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Here is the result from `/sbin/ifconfig`:

[image]

As you can see both NICs received an static IP address.

The strange problem is that you can ping/access only the IP from `eth1`.
So again even when I have two NICs I have only one IP for that machine.

Where is my mistake, why I can not reach/access/ping the IP from `eth0` from another machine ?

You can try the ping also and you will see.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: You have not statically assigned IP addresses, you have dynamically assigned them.  Your problem is you have 2 interfaces on the same subnet/ A better way would be to bond the 2 interfaces into a single interface and then bring up a secondary interface on it if you need 2 IP's.

Comment: How can i create another subnet ? How can i create 2 interfaces ? I do not understand it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because the system with two NICs is trying to send the reply ICMP ping message from `eth0` out of `eth1`.

When your system sends traffic out to the network, it consults its local Forwarding Information Base (FIB), or routing table.

The routing table will have a list of subnets and interfaces where that subnet can be reached.  Each outgoing packet is compared against every entry in this table, and the one with the highest subnet CIDR number will "win" and be used to send the traffic.  If there are no winners the default gateway is used.

You have 2 entries with the same subnet CIDR going to the same subnet.  Essentially, as far as your system is concerned, these go to the same place so it does not matter which is used.  Your network stack is going to use the first one it encounters, send the traffic out of it, and then be done with it.  Probably the NIC with the lowest IP number is appearing first in your routing table.

You need to look into Linux's policy routing features (Google "policy routing" and good luck because I'm studying it myself), or look into redirecting traffic with `iptables` if you really want to do this.

Comment: you don't use policy routing to solve this problem, you use channel bonding.

Answer (score 1):

**The simple way**

At your level of knowledge, it might be best to ignore the second NIC (ie disconnect it) and have 2 IP addresses bound to the first NIC.    The disadvantages are lack of redundancy and you are limited to the speed of 1 NIC.

To do this (for eth0), modify your /etc/network/interfaces file to read:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address A.A.A.A
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway X.X.X.X

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address B.B.B.B
netmask 255.255.252.0
```

Note that you will need to put in the correct gateway address for X.X.X.X.   You will also need to make sure that the IP addresses (A.A.A.A and B.B.B.B) are not in the DHCP range.

**The hard way**

The idea here is to make the 2 interfaces act as 1 double speed interface (with the ability to continue work if an interface is unplugged), and then bring up the IP addresses similar to above.

The first difficulty to overcome is to work out what mode to use.  There is no one-size fits all solution here, its the matter of choosing the most appropriate one for you and your hardware.  Have a look [here](http://www.cloudibee.com/network-bonding-modes/) for a description of different modes.  If in doubt, use mode 0 - this does not require fancy hardware, but you can only get the full effect of channel bonding for outbound traffic, but you still get redundancy.  If you have traffic for lots of different addresses on the LAN, mode 2 is not a bad choice either.

You need to create a file like /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf to tell the system about how you want to do the bonding

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=0 miimon=100
```

(The above assumes you are using mode 0).

The easiest way to make this change come into effect is to reboot your computer.

You will now have a new interface available on your system "bond0".  Using /etc/networks/interfaces you now enslave the 2 ethernet interfaces and then bring up the virtual interfaces as per example 1 above.

So the file will look like

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Enslave the ethernet drivers
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth1

# The primary network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address A.A.A.A
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway X.X.X.X

auto bond0:1
iface bond0:1 inet static
address B.B.B.B
netmask 255.255.252.0
```

Comment: I have a question for the simple way. Does the eth0:1 will have different MAC address from eth0 ? I need two different mac addresses.

Comment: No, it will only provide 1 ethernet address.   Maybe you should describe your end goal, rather then make an assumption of how to reach it ?  I note that both IP addresses are in the same subnet - so the question is why do you need 2 mac addresses?   Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/223601/multiple-mac-addresses-on-one-physical-network-interface-linux

Comment: I need 2 mac addresses because i must give my ISP the MAC address and they give me a static IP address for the MAC.

Comment: This raises a number of questions you should clarify with your ISP when looking for a solution - While it would seem that your ISP can/is allocating you static IP's over DHCP, can you set the IP addresses up using statics on your config instead, and if you bring up a static IP address not associated with a MAC address, will it work, and (because you are statically assigning your addresses on your side), can they have the same MAC associated with 2 IP's.

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/223601/multiple-mac-addresses-on-one-physical-network-interface-linux (but replace eth0 with bond0) to create vlans with different MAC addresses appearing on the interface.  Note the format is bondX.X rather then bondX:X

Comment: I have an web interface which was delivered to my by the ISP. There i place an MAC and they give me a static IP. I can place twice same MAC and they give me two different IP Static addresses. So with one NIC eth0 and eth0:0 i can have two IPs for my machine with one MAC address for both ?

Comment: Yes, using eth0 and eth0:1 you can have 2 IP's associated with 1 MAC address - this is standard practice.  You probably can't use DHCP though (as the DHCP server relies on the MAC address to work out which IP to provide), so you will need to use static addressing.

Comment: So i have to get the gateway and setup my configuration properly. Is it a problem that the two IPs seems to be in one DHCP range. They are `46.10.222.174` and `46.10.222.142` ? Any idea how can i understand my netmask and gateway ?

Comment: You would only set the gateway on eth0, not eth0:1.   DHCP is irrelevant to you as you need to use static IP's.  The netmask is 255.255.252.0 - which defines the subnet -  all IP's between 46.10.220.0 and 46.10.223.255.  You can get the gateway by typing ip route show | grep "default"' - the result will be default via XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - this XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the gateway.  A gateway is an IP in the network through which unknown traffic is sent. A netmask is a mathematical notation which defines a group of addresses.

Comment: can we ho to chat ? I think i am near to complete the configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37676/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-davidgo).